# React App can't load after refresh on ie11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, internet-explorer-11

I work on a quite big ReactJS project. It loads properly in IE11, but breaks on refresh. White blank page is all I got. Refreshing worked fine when I've opened dev tools. I've read something about console not beeing initiated until I go to devtools and it could be an issue because my app and some dependencies use console.logs. I've added a polyfill for this:
https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill
And it stoped refreshing even with dev tools. What can cause the problem? Also, this problem doesnt occur on local environment, only after deployment. I can't really attach any code as it's a big project which includes many subprojects built with lerna and I've got no clue where the problem could be. Console doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: IE11 or IE in general is no longer developed or supported, don't use it.

Comment: @Codebeat unfortunately, lots of customers are using IE in my usecase :(

Comment: Does it show any console error when it gets break? I am not sure about your purpose of using the `console.log` for a production version. If it is not necessary then just for testing purposes, can you please try to remove it from the production version may help to fix the issue. If possible then you can provide the steps to reproduce the issue may help us to understand it in a better way.